# Problema al ejecutar `apt-get install` como root

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Mi versión de ubuntu es 16.04.6 lts. El error que me sale es el siguiente:

```
**Reading package lists... Error!
E: Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease - mkstemp (2: No such file or directory)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.****
```

espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists /tmp
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

hay una comunidad de linux

https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: gracias, fue de gran ayuda

Comment: @MaraMosqueraShrsa si la respuesta te fue de ayuda, no olvides marcarla como correcta haciendo clic en la palomita. Saludos